# Android search contacts by phone number and contact name (Both in same time)

Tags: android

I want to query on contacts by phone number and contact name in same time with "LIKE" operator, here is my code :

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1 AND (" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '" + query + "%' OR " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE '%" + query + "%' OR " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE '%" + query + "%' ) ", null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    return cursor;
```

But my code does not work, it's crashes and android says "data4" and "data1" column does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to find contact by name

```
public String findByName(Context context , String name) {  
   String result= null;
            String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'";
            String[] projection = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, selection, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                result= c.getString(0);
            }
            c.close();
            if(result==null)
                result= "This contact is not saved into your device";
            return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loader to get fastest results.

```
public Loader<Cursor> getContactCursor(Context context, Bundle args) {
        Uri baseUri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;  
        String filter = args != null ? args.getString("filter") : null;
        if (filter != null && filter.length() > 0) {
            return new CursorLoader(context,baseUri, null, "(display_name LIKE ?) OR (data1 LIKE ?)", new String[]{"%" + filter + "%","%" + filter + "%"}, null);
        }else{
            return new CursorLoader(context,baseUri, projection,null, null, null);
        }

    }
```